# How to "'validate and lazy swap' atomically" like CAS?

Tags: java, multithreading, atomic, compare-and-swap

Here is prototype of function I want:

```
atomicReference.validateAndSwap(value -> isInvalid(value), () -> createValid());
```

It assumed to be called from multiple threads.
Second lambda is called only when first returns `true`.
First (plus second if first returns `true`) lambda calls should be a single atomic operation.

It is even possible to implement without `synchronized`?
Are there ready solutions for similar functionality?
Have I wrong way of thinking and miss something?

Comment: "It is even possible to implement without synchronized?" - Nope.

Comment: Are the objects here immutable?  If not, is their 'validity' at least immutable?  If both answers are 'no', then I suspect you are overlooking something very fundamental about safely sharing mutable state.  If either answer is 'yes', this _may_ be possible, but it would require you to relax your requirement that the lambdas invocations occur as an atomic unit.  That shouldn't be a problem if validity is indeed immutable, unless you are adamant about not generating garbage.

Comment: Also, if you could provide more background about what you are ultimately trying to do, we could offer more useful feedback and perhaps suggest a better 'tool' for the job.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure whether you mean the right thing when saying “*First (plus second if first returns true) lambda calls should be a single atomic operation.*” The point of atomic references is that the update function evaluation *may* overlap and therefore, should not have interference, but will act as if being atomic, as when evaluations overlap, only one can succeed with `CAS` and the other has to be repeated based on the new value.

If you want truly atomic evaluations, using a `Lock` or `synchronized` is unavoidable. If you have appropriate non-interfering functions and want implement updates as if atomic, it can be implemented like

```
Value old;
do old = atomicReference.get();
   while(isInvalid(old) && !atomicReference.compareAndSet(old, createValid()));
```

Since in this specific case, the `createValid()` function does not depend on the old value, we could avoid repeated evaluation in the contended case:

```
Value old = atomicReference.get();
if(isInvalid(old)) {
  Value newValue = createValid();
  while(!atomicReference.compareAndSet(old, newValue)) {
    old=atomicReference.get();
    if(!isInvalid(old)) break;
  }
}
```

That all assuming that the validity of an object cannot change in-between. Otherwise, locking or synchronizing is unavoidable.

Note that the Java 8’s update methods follow the same principle. So you can write

```
atomicReference.updateAndGet(old -> isInvalid(old)? createValid(): old);
```

to achieve the same, but it also isn’t truly atomic but rather behaves as-if atomic if concurrent evaluations of the update function have no interference.

Comment: what would be the point in doing `while(isInvalid(old) && !atomicReference.compareAndSet(old, createValid()))` if the object can not change in between?

Comment: @Eugene: this is a `do … while` loop; that’s why I indented the `while` line. Unfortunately, it didn’t fit into one line.

Comment: I meant a different thing, but I think I understood it now. that's actually pretty nice, so if `isInvalid` returns true, you are trying to CAS old with a valid one; if that fails it means atomicReference has changed (most probably with a valid value). And you are trying again, but first checking if that value is valid...

Comment: the second approach is even nicer. If this `atomicReference.compareAndSet` fails, it means that `atomicReference` has changed and you are reading the new value that was set and cheking if this new one is valid, repeating if necessary.